# Adding PHP code into a form action prints data outside the form

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add the following code into the action portion of my form:

```
action="'.the_permalink().'?filename.php=1"
```

But this only adds `?filename.php=1` to the form action and the_permalink() result is printed outside the form before the form even starts!

This is my form line:

```
form name="front_end_aa" method="POST" action="".the_premalink()."?assign-journalist=1"
```

`the_permalink()` is a function within wordpress to get the link of the post you are clicking.

**Solved: This was solved thanks to @enenen:**

Store the results of the PHP into a variable, and append the variable into the form action like this:

`$permalink = get_permalink();`

`echo '<form name="front_end_aa" method="POST" action="'.$permalink.'?filename=1">`

Comment: Did you refer yourself to : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink ? Are you in a WordPress loop ?

Comment: Could you provide the whole row where is `action=...` and the code for `the_permalink()` function please.

Comment: @enenen Sure check my original question

Comment: @Matt, I added an answer below. But I still think that you can't ask your question properly or I can't understand what you need actually. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still couldn't understand where you write your `form` tag. So...

If it is plain html it will be:

```
<form name="front_end_aa" method="POST" action="<?php the_premalink(); ?>?assign-journalist=1">
```

And if it is inside PHP code it will be:

```
echo "<form name='front_end_aa' method='POST' action='".the_premalink()."?assign-journalist=1'>";
```

Comment: @ enenen I have changed it slightly to this `echo '<form name="front_end_aa" method="POST" action="'.the_permalink().'?assign-journalist=1">` but it is still putting the permalink outside of the action and the form tags

Comment: I'm not sure how `the_permalink()` actually works. Maybe you can try to get the URL with something like `$permalink = get_permalink();` and then use `$permalink` when `echo`ing.

Answer (score 0):

```
action="<?php echo_the_permalink(); ?>?rest_part_of=url"
```

Anyway, it's ugly. What about write a function which renders the whole URL?

```
action="<?php echo_whole_url(1); ?>"
```

where *1* is the parameter of the url?

Comment: is it possible to implement that code in here pastebin.com/RJXAwfWi

Answer (score 0):

You need a variable that stores the value which is created by the_permalink():

```
$myLink = the_permalink();
echo '<form action="'.$myLink.'?filename.php=1">';
```

That should do the trick. Or try the answer of ern0

Comment: this works kind of but it spits it out in the HTML as `http://custard-clients.co.uk/regionalfeed/web/gregre/<form action="?assign-journalist=1" method="POST" name="front_end_aa">` I need the link to be before the ? in the action